# Callout Exception when testing

Tags: unit-test, callout, exception

I use a webservice to validate government info on companies. This is used for accounts and Cases. For some reason I'm getting this calloutException but there's no DML before the callout. I'm getting the **System.calloutException : You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out**

Let me explain the logic: on After insert/update there's a triggere that checks whether or not the record needs to go throug validation. than it calls a future method (where the callout happens) and update the records. Inside the future method I select the ids sent from the trigger and call the service for each one of them adding them to a list that is updated after the loop is done.

There are three main code parts:
Case decision on calling or not the validation service:

```
    for (Case c : cases2update) {
        if (needsValidation) {
            setCases.add(c.id);
        } else {
            c.InfoSimples_Status__c = 'Approved';
        }
    }

    if (setCases.size() > 0) {
        sendToInfoSimples(setCases); // futureMethod
    }

    Utility.updateTriggerDisabled(cases2update); // updates without triggers
```

This is the future method:

```
 @future(Callout=true)
public static void sendToInfoSimplesService(Set<String> setCasesIds) {
    system.debug('InfoSimples_CaseHandler.sendToInfoSimplesService()');
    List<Case> lstCasesToValidate = [SELECT Id, Tax_ID_Number__c, Br_State_Tax_Number__c, Razao_Social__c, City__c, Postal_Code__c, Modality_TAX__c, 
                                     Region__c, Street_Address_1__c, InfoSimples_Status__c, Country__c, House_Number__c, Street_Address_2__c, Street_Address_3__c,
                                     InfoSimples_Has_Centralized_IE__c, InfoSimples_Has_Centralized_Tax__c
                                     FROM Case 
                                     WHERE Id IN :setCasesIds 
                                     AND ( RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Brazil_CMR' OR RecordType.DeveloperName = 'RES_BR_RT_Regime_Especial'
                                        OR RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Brazil_DMU')];

    InfoSimples_CaseServiceHandler.callInfoSimples(lstCasesToValidate);
}
```

and this is the method with the loop (called from the future méthod). the method validate infoSimples has no DML.

```
public static void callInfoSimples(list<case> casesToValidate) {
    List<Integration_Message__c> messages = new List<Integration_Message__c>();
    InfoSimples_Callout callout = new InfoSimples_Callout();

    for (Case c: casesToValidate) {
        validateinfoSimples (c, callout, messages);
    }

    system.debug ('----- updating Cases -----');
    LenovoUtility.updateTriggerDisabled(casesToValidate);
    if(messages.size() > 0) {
        Utility.insertTriggerDisabled(messages);
    }
}
```

The validation method, the manage methods for Receita and integra are just setting attribute values to the Case, converting values from the response JSON to the proper fields

```
private static void validateInfoSimples (Case c, InfoSimples_Callout callout, list<integration_message__c> messages) {
    InfoSimples_CaseServiceHandler handler = new InfoSimples_CaseServiceHandler();

    InfoSimples_ReceitaResponseClass.Data receitaData;
    InfoSimples_SintegraResponseClass.Data sintegraData;

    boolean serviceStatus = false;

    try {
        if (c.Tax_ID_number__c.length() > 11) {
            receitaData = callout.ReceitaCallout(c.id, c.Tax_ID_Number__c, messages);
        } else {
            receitaData = null;
        }

        if (receitaData != null) {
            serviceStatus = handler.manageReceita (c, callout, receitaData);
        }

        if (serviceStatus) {
            serviceStatus = false;
            sintegraData = callout.SintegraCallout(c.id, c.Tax_ID_Number__c, c.Region__c.toLowerCase(), messages);

            if (sintegraData != null) {
                serviceStatus = handler.manageSintegra(c, sintegraData);
            }
        }

        if (serviceStatus && callout.isSuframa(c.Region__c)) {
            sintegraData = callout.SintegraCallout(c.id, c.Tax_ID_Number__c, 'suframa', messages);
            if (sintegraData != null) {
                handler.manageSuframa(c, sintegraData);
            }
        }

        if (serviceStatus) {
            c.InfoSimples_Status__c = 'Approved';
        } else {
            c.InfoSimples_Status__c = 'Rejected';
            c.InfoSimples_Email__c = true;
        }

        c = handler.fillICMSTaxPayerLogic(c);

    } catch (InfoSimples_Callout.InfoSimplesTimeOutException timeOut) {
        c.InfoSimples_Status__c = 'Timed Out';
    } catch (System.Exception e) {
        c.InfoSimples_Status__c = 'Error';
        messages.add(LenovoUtility.CreateIntegrationMessage('000', 'Exception Error ' + e, 'INFO_SIMPLES', '', c.Id));
    }
}
```

Callout class

```
Http http = new Http();

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(this.endPointReceita.replace('{CNPJCODE}', taxCode));
    req.setMethod('GET');

    InfoSimples_ReceitaResponseClass.ReceitaResponse receita = null;
    system.debug('Receita Endpoint: ' + req.getEndpoint());

    string information = '';
    HttpResponse res = http.send(req);

    if( res.getStatusCode() == 200 ) {
        receita = InfoSimples_ReceitaResponseClass.parse(res.getBody());
        if( receita.code == 200 || receita.code == 201) {

            information = ErrorAditionalInformation(receita.data);
            messages.add(LenovoUtility.CreateIntegrationMessage(string.valueOf(res.getStatusCode()), receita.code_message + ' - ' + information, 'RECEITA/CNPJ', req.getEndpoint(), res.getBody(), objId));

        } else if (receita.code == 605 || receita.code == 609 || receita.code == 613 || receita.code == 614 || 
                   receita.code == 615 || receita.code == 616 || receita.code == 618) {
            information = 'RECEITA - timeout: ' + receita.code_message;           
            messages.add(LenovoUtility.CreateIntegrationMessage(string.valueOf(res.getStatusCode()), information, 'RECEITA/CNPJ', req.getEndpoint(), objId));
            throw new InfoSimples_Callout.InfoSimplesTimeOutException (information, 'RECEITA - ' + receita.code);

        } else { // service dont found values                           
            information = receita.code_message != NULL ? res.getStatus() + ' - ' + receita.code_message : res.getStatus();
            messages.add(LenovoUtility.CreateIntegrationMessage(string.valueOf(res.getStatusCode()), information, 'RECEITA/CNPJ', req.getEndpoint(), objId));
            receita = null;   
        }

    } else if (res.getStatusCode() == 408 || res.getStatusCode() == 504 || res.getStatusCode() == 599) {
        information = receita.code_message + ' Integration Error, contact the administrator';
        messages.add(LenovoUtility.CreateIntegrationMessage(string.valueOf(res.getStatusCode()), information, 'RECEITA/CNPJ', req.getEndpoint(), objId));                
        throw new InfoSimples_Callout.InfoSimplesTimeOutException(information, 'HTTP - ' + res.getStatusCode());

    } else {
        information = receita.code_message + ' Integration Error, contact the administrator';
        messages.add(LenovoUtility.CreateIntegrationMessage(string.valueOf(res.getStatusCode()), information, 'RECEITA/CNPJ', req.getEndpoint(), objId));
        receita = null;
    }

    return (receita != null) ? receita.data : null;
```

EDIT: added more code parts
The exception I receiving is none of the expected ones like a custom exception for time outs

Comment: We need to see more of your code. What you have posted paints a quite incomplete picture, so it is nearly impossible to confirm your assessment or help point out what operation you might get tripped on.

Comment: Also, what is the specific exception you are getting?

Comment: I'd recommend capturing the debug log when the exception occurs. You can then scan back through the log for any DML statements. As this is a test case, ensure you are using `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` to isolate the test data setup from the core test itself.